# HttpWebRequest - differentiating client and server exceptions

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

Suppose the regular way of handling http web response exceptions:

```
void BeginGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var req = asyncResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = req.EndGetResponse(asyncResult) as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that a WebException with the same error code ("not found") may be thrown if either there is a connectivity issue to the server or if the server actually replies with a "not found" status. This seems like a fault in HttpWebRequest's implementation.

How should we then properly differentiate such situations, i.e. whether the exception thrown "originates" on the client or on the server ?

Edit1: i'm running this code on the Windows Phone 7.1 platform.

Edit2: the suggested WebException's Status property is practically useless on WP7, since it's always set to UnknownError, even when it should be ProtocolError. Possible HttpWebRequest implementation fault on WP7 ?

Edit3: the MSDN documentation page for WebException.Status in Silverlight states that the ProtocolError enum member is not supported, so this explains it... No idea though why it's unsupported.

Comment: You might want to look at the [Status member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx) of the exception you get back - [one of its values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx) will help you decide where the error has occured.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the `Status` field of the `WebException`.  That will help tell you, at a high level, where the error occurred.  You can find the docs for it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx) and a very simple piece of sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx).

Comment: When i looked up the documentation i hoped you were right, WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError is the value that i needed, but unfortunately the status is always set to WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError. I should've mentioned first: the code runs on the Windows Phone 7.1 platform.

Comment: @GabrielS. Have you also looked at the exception's full Message property?  InnerException?  etc.

Comment: i just have, but there's nothing useful or reliable to help me. "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." as the message in both cases, same inner exception... The only vaguely helpful indicator is that the WebException.Response.StatusDescription, together with some other members, are an empty string when the server does not actually respond, which i find rather unsatisfactory.

Comment: How about - checking to see if the exception has a response, and whether that response has an http status code?

Comment: @Andras. good idea, already tried that, but in both cases the answer is yes and the response code is NotFound. So it's useless for my requirements.